# python packages not available to script executed from cron

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have developed a python Flask API and deployed it on aws ebs. 
The Flask API works as expected. The Flask API requires several python packages that I have installed by adding them to:
`requirements.txt`

I have a python script also installed which is separate py file from the Flask API. It is scheduled to run daily executed by cron.

When I setup cron, I get an execution error that module is not found:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

However module was installed by `requirements.txt` and is available to the Flask API code. How is it that `import pandas` work with the Flask API but is unavailable to the python script that is executed by cron?

Comment: Does your code run inside a virtual environment, and if so, is the cron entry set up to run inside the same environment?

Comment: you might need to have your cron line as something like `workon myenv && python /path/to/script.py`

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs run outside of your environment, so that means they don't have your `$PATH` and other environmental variables (broader description in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working#answer-23438) answer) which makes then unable to find certain programs. What you should do is to make your Python script execution wrapped in a bash script where at the beginning you export all the needed environmental variables (or generally make it use your environment). Then, execute this bash script with your cron.

Answer (score 0):

@arudzinska is right. My case is using Elastic Beanstalk AWS and cronjob having the same issue with pandas (No module named 'pandas').
I used the comments above and try to find where the pandas package is and then to find the python path where requirements.txt packages are installed and put it all together into .config file: 

1. Pandas path:

`find . -name pandas
./opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas`

2. Python path

2.1. what is the system path into the console

```
eb ssh
which python3
```

/usr/bin/python3

2.2. Find your python path

```
find . -name python
```

./opt/python/run/baselinenv/bin/python 
./opt/python/run/venv/bin/python

3. App file

   `find . -name apps.py`

/opt/python/current/app/apps.py

4. Modified the cronjob.config file at .ebextensions

`files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            15 6 * * * root echo $(date) >> /tmp/cron.log; /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh >> /tmp/cron_py.log 2>&1;`

```
"/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        #!/bin/bash

        date > /tmp/date
        # Your actual script content
        /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3 /opt/python/current/app/apps.py

        exit 0
```

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"

And now everything is working.